# Showing only current authenticated user orders in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, eloquent

I'm creating an API for the android developer to be able to show the orders made by user.My code makes any user show any product, what I want is only showing orders made by authenticated user

I've protected the route like that:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group( function () {
    Route::resource('orders', 'API\OrdersController');
});
```

and I use the following headers on the request:

```
'headers' => [    'Accept' => 'application/json',    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,]
```

here is the controller code of the show($id) method

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = Auth::id();
    $Orders = Orders::where('id',$id)->where('order_shopper_id', $user)->get();
    if (is_null($Orders) || empty($Orders)) {
        return $this->sendError('Orders not found.');
    }
    return $this->sendResponse($Orders->toArray(), 'Orders retrieved successfully.');
 }
```

it works but when for example I try to access order number "2" and the authenticated user didn't create that order, it still returns success with empty data.

All I want is, "Select Order Number (#) but make sure that the logged in user had created that order not someone else, if not return unAuthenticated"

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's in `$user`? Can you check it? return it and see if it's empty or not.

Comment: It returns the the current authenticated user id

Comment: Just use this `if ($Orders)` it will work.

Comment: It RETURNS or you expect that it return the user id? Because I think you must use api guard.

Comment: I have tested it with Postman, and as long as I'm using the token, it returns the id, and I'm using api guard.
I will look it up though to see if I should use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QueryBuilder::get()` method returns a collection, a empty collection is still a collection object, so the `$Orders` never will be null or empty.

Try:

```
if (!$Orders->count()) {
    return $this->sendError('Orders not found.');
}
```

Comment: That wasn't exactly what I'm looking for, but it did the job

Answer (score 1):

If you authenticate the user based on token, you have to get the authenticated user id this way:

```
$user = Auth::guard('api')->id();
```

And change the `if` statement as @kiske has said.

Comment: I do authenticate users based on tokens, and I'm not using that way and it is still working, but anyways I'll look it up

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if($Orders->isEmpty()){
 return $this->sendError('Orders not found.');
}
```